# Debugger for C# and C++ in the same solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm working on an universal app with visual studio and I'm using a custom MFT wrote in C++.
The problem is since I'm using the debugger for the C++ project, I can't use the debugger for the C# project anymore. For example if I put some breaking point in my main Class in the C# project, visual studio says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

Comment: I would create a new soluition with the C# code only -or- load the same solution, in another VS instance. Perhaps you could launch the debugger from the other instance, and/or attach to the C# process?

Comment: I can't because I'm calling function from C++ in C#. I tried to launch the debugger from the C# project, it didn't work.

Comment: Launch separately and attach to process (making sure that "native" is also selected for debugging), or go and set all of the debugger settings -- "Enable native code debugging". Second option is more convenient, but can make debugging slower.

Comment: How can i launch separately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally Debug -> properties and then for application process and background task process switch between native only and managed only, depending if you are debugging the C++ or the C#